# MySQL autoincrement tied with an attribute

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Is it possible to have a column say ORDER in a table to autoincrement only when inserting a new ID? So say I have the following column:

```
ID ORDER
1    0
1    1
1    2
1    3
1    4
```

When I insert another ID order increments to 5, when I insert 2 as a new ID order starts from 0.

Comment: If this is just for ordering why not just have a standard auto increment column? You'll have gaps in the `order` field when looking at one group but the order within the group will still be correct.

Comment: well if that's the case then am I just wasting a bunch of space?

Comment: how do you write a trigger for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example uses a composite index but numbering starts from 1

```
create table test (
  id smallint not null,
  norder int unsigned not null auto_increment,
  primary key (id,norder)
) engine=myisam;

insert into test(id) values (1),(1),(1),(2),(3),(1),(1),(4),(5),(1)
```

If you want that it starts from zero you need a trigger as already said.

Comment: actually it is possible to start counting from 0 with your method as explays mysql documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_auto_value_on_zero , anyway it is not a recommended practice starting from 0

Comment: so you're just setting id and no order as primary key no order as auto_increment and this automatically work? didn't know that..